# Why women are not called gentle?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, speech

Avoj friends I have a question - When the host say "Ladies and gentlemen" why they don't put gentle before Ladies? I think ladies are more gentle than men. Why not it be "men and gentle-ladies"?
Thank you

Comment: They often are.  "Gentlemen" is just referring to men who are not somehow crude, while women are generally assumed to be not crude unless noted otherwise.

Comment: There are gentlewomen.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390406/the-use-of-the-term-gentlewoman

Comment: Unless I've been led astray, the "gentle" refers to "landed gentry" more than a meek demeanor.

Comment: You’ve accounted for the shift from “man” to “gentleman” but not the shift from “woman” to “lady”.

Comment: @Lawrence - _Lord_ and _Lady_ were originally the feudal 'lord of the manor' and his wife; with the development of the peerage they became forms of address for aristocrats. _Lady_ evolved into a general term for a woman of a certain status and thence into a polite way of referring to a woman.

Answer (score 0):

*Gentle* in this context doesn't mean 'kind and tender', it means 'of superior social status (but not an aristocrat)'. The historical usage of *lady* and *gentleman* is complicated, but basically in the past both terms referred to people of a certain social rank, but are now just a polite way of referring to any woman and man.

Comment: Yes, they were "gentlefolk" as opposed to "common people". The fact that gentlefolk could be, and often were, violent, vindictive and cruel didn't stop them having the status of gentlefolk. In fact a lot of them achieved that status through violence and cruelty.