# Is there an opposite gender for "lady"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-positive

I have been wondering about this little problem for a while now. Everyone understands that, in the binary, the opposite of 'man' is 'woman', and the opposite of 'gentleman' is, namely, 'gentlewoman'.

However, from what I can tell, there seems to be no word that refers to the opposite gender of the word 'lady'. Any ideas?

Comment: Gentlewoman is archaic. I am sure you have heard "Ladies and gentlemen" being said...

Comment: @fev that's a very good point, thanks for the example.

Comment: @fev: "Gentlewoman" is still in active use in the United States Congress.

Comment: Note the start of some speeches: "Ladies and gentlemen", and in the correct context "My lords, ladies and gentlemen"

Comment: Use of the word Gentlewoman in the US Congress  ...  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390406/the-use-of-the-term-gentlewoman

Comment: Sometimes, if only one lady is present some (British, native) speakers say "Lady, and gentlemen". To my ears that is awkward. The vocative singular of "ladies" is "Madam", so "Madam and gentlemen" would be more to my taste.

Comment: If you're talking about nobility, it's "lord" or if you're using it to refer to gender, it's "gent".

Comment: In England, there used to be a class distinction among female football clubs: those calling themselves *Ladies* tended to be more working class than those calling themselves *Women*.  In recent decades, the large majority have renamed themselves from Ladies to Women, though there are still curiosities such as the distinct [Cardiff City Ladies F.C.](https://www.cardiffclfc.com) and [Cardiff City Women](https://www.cardiffcityfc.co.uk/search?results_for=women)

Comment: How about "ydal"??

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Etymologically, the male counterpart of *lady* is *lord.*  Idiomatically, it is *gentleman.*

*Lady* comes from an Old English compound noun meaning roughly "loaf kneader," whereas *lord* comes from a compound noun meaning "loaf keeper" or "loaf protector."

The etymological counterpart of *gentleman,* which is indeed *gentlewoman,* is used infrequently these days, usually in historical or quasi-historical contexts.

This is a good example of the etymological fallacy: you often cannot determine what a word means today by looking into its origins.

Comment: This is interesting but some references would be good, either to the books you consulted or [etymology online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lady)

Comment: +1 for the last sentence especially.  Sometimes the original meaning of a word can be the exact or near opposite of it's current meaning.  ['Egregious'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egregious) is a good example.

Comment: @JimmyJames "Awful" is another good example

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, agreed.  Although your response made me notice that I used the wrong form of 'its' on an English forum so now I kind of hate myself.

Comment: Note that *lord* is ultimately a contraction of Old English *hlafweard* (*loafward*).

Comment: @Dan and a warder is someone who guards/protects, which is exactly what phoog said.

Comment: For the remnant of lady and lord usage, see some common law courts where "My Lord" and "My Lady" are still used (or used until recently) to address judges depending on the gender.

Comment: @phoog thank you for such a concise answer! I suppose a common example of this lord/lady usage is when we talk about a "landlord" or "landlady"..

Comment: @Insatiable Evidence for idiomatic usage can be found in the common opening to a speech "Ladies and Gentlemen".  Also, in US military courtesy, "gentlemen" is used to address a group of male officers and "ladies" is used to address a group of female officers.

Comment: As to the first paragraph, I suspect the distinction is not etymology vs idiomatic usage, but rather proper nouns (Lord and Lady, the titles) versus common nouns (gentleman and lady meaning someone who follows etiquette). One can be a Lady but not a lady, or vice versa. While "lady" may have originated from "Lady" originally, they are distinctly different in meaning. Note that I'm using capitalization to easily distinguish between the two here, the capitalization is not enshrined in the definition of the word itself.

Comment: @StuartF One book which discusses the origins of "lord" and "lady" from "hlafweard" and "hlafdige" is *The Wordhord: Daily Life in Old English* by Hana Videen.

Comment: @Flater yes, the correct answer to the question is really "it depends which meaning of *lady* you are talking about".

Answer (score 0):

### Gentleman.

In addition to 'lord', as pointed out by phoog's excellent answer, there is another male counterpart to the appellation of 'lady': 'gentleman'. Both of these titles refered to members of the petty nobility, which gradually came to refer to members of the well-mannered upper class in general: a wealthy man was a gentleman, and his wife was a lady. Over time, this use was gradually used to refer to more and more people until this class-based definition fell out of use, which is why an announcer at an event might start a speech by addressing those present as "ladies and gentlemen".

Comment: phoog mentioned that, too.

Comment: @Heartspring My point is that 'gentleman' isnt just the idiomatic counterpart of 'lady', it's also the literal counterpart thanks to them both (originally) referring to petty nobility/the moneyed upper classes.